# Node.js example on Google Cloud, wrong syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I just took two lines from Google Cloud examples for Node.js here:

```
Listing Buckets  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets#storage-list-buckets-nodejs

The two lines are

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
```

To my surprise I got the following error when running this in Firebase:

```
info: TypeError: Storage is not a constructor
```

I don't recognize the syntax, seems a bit odd to me, but anyway it is Google's example. I have no idea why it doesn't work. Could it be that I am using this in Firebase. I just serving it locally:

```
firebase serve
```

The function comes up fine, but crashes with the error above when I call it:

```
+  functions: test: http://localhost:5001/myproj/us-central1/test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah that syntax doesn't seem to work. I was able to get it working using the following syntax

```
import * as storage from '@google-cloud/storage';

const client = new storage.Storage();
```

Edit: Looks like it's a known bug, here's a [closed issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/456) about it

Comment: Thanks. Wonder why they do not correct the docs? (I filed in issue, but didn't get a reply.)

Comment: Hm, but there is still something I do not understand. It looks like they are saying that this is TypeScript. However I am not using TypeScript (as far as I know). What is going on there?

Comment: That's a good question , I guess they plan to fix it soon. About the last question, they were talking about `import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';` throwing an error (`node_modules/@types/google-cloud__storage/index"' has no exported member 'Storage'.`) in Typescript (which was not directly related to your problem cause you are not using Typescript). So they probably changed the way they were importing/exporting the submodules, I'm not sure though.

Comment: @Leo: Could you give me the issue report number so that I would be able to follow up the report? Otherwise I will report it to the documentation team to make the correction.

Comment: @Katayoon, unfortunately not. I reported it on the documentation page.